# Laravel 8 config:cache allowing sending emails but can't read env variables after config:cache

Tags: php, laravel, command-line-interface, laravel-8, laravel-artisan

hope you are all fine. I am facing an issue when I am running command

`php artisan config:cache`

email is **sending** but I can't  **read** `env('DB_HOST')` variables.

Similarly when I run then this time:

`php artisan config:clear`

email is **not sending**, now I can **read** `env('DB_HOST')` variables.

I don't understand what is issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#configuration-caching

You must be use correspond config. IN your case

```
config('database.connections.mysql.host')
```

Comment: thanks for answering. I understand your point for reading env variables but when I run `php artisan config:clear` in the development process then why email is not sending. All emil configurations are fine in env file.